# PHP connection to MySQL database not connecting?

Tags: php, mysql

I've just started learning php and I'm having trouble finding the problem when I get it to connect to the database and run an 'INSERT' query. I think the problem is in my connection.php file.

insert.php:

```
<?PHP
echo "into";
include("connection.php");
echo "connected";
$table = blog;
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table SET
Title = '$_POST[title]',
Description = '$_POST[description]',
Content = '$_POST[content]'";
$query = @mysql_query($sql);

echo "complete";

echo $_POST[title];
echo $_POST[description];
echo $_POST[content]; 
?>
```

connection.php:

```
<?php
echo "connection file reached";
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, user, pass);
mysql_select_db(test, $conn);
echo "connected";
?>
```

Any advice on my code, or how I could solve this problem would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I'm thinking that it never gets to the connection.php file because it shows the "into" at the top of insert.php but not the "connection file reached" at the top of connection.php. Is that call correct to that file?

Thanks

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO to prevent SQL-Injections.

Comment: Its only on a local server so that shouldn't be too much of a problem will it?

Comment: `$table` is not defined.

Comment: set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: get the error
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>

Comment: @u_mulder $table = blog; isn't that defining it?

Comment: @andrew where would that go?

Comment: The use of mysql_* functions is discouraged, because they may be removed in newer versions of PHP. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: @Airglow right at the top of the code you posted here after `<?php`

Comment: This line $table = blog... it seems to me it should be $table = "blog", unless you have already defined blog as a constant. And if this is the case, be aware of the convention about constant naming: http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php

Comment: @ederpsampaio php will assume `'blog'` if blog is undefined, but you're right you shouldn't rely on it

Comment: @andrew after adding that code I got this: Parse error: parse error in ../Test/connection.php on line 3

Comment: This is the point, @andrew. We already have lots of sources of errors, then we shouldn't rely on anything when we can prevent strange behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Readup on php constants, variables and strings!

```
define('foo','bar'); // foo == 'bar';
$foo = 'bar'; // $foo == 'bar'
```

Please use `mysqli_*` as `mysql_*` is depreciated.

```
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, user, pass);
```

probably should be

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. It went through and said connected etc but the db is still empty, any ideas on this?

Comment: I would install phpmyadmin on your setup xamp or whatever your using, and start by copying in the result of `echo $sql` it will help you debug your query

Comment: i have Sequel Pro running and can see the database

Answer (score 0):

you have written

```
@mysql_query($sql)
```

as well as a lot other problem it's structure is also wrong the problem might be from version of your language as recommendation of php you should not use mysql any more use mysqli or PDO